# Class 1, 4-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, hamiltonicity

A graph is 4-regular if all its vertices are of degree 4.  It is class 1 if the set of edges of the graph can be partitioned into perfect matchings; alternatively, if it can be edge-4-colored.  A subgraph of a graph $G$ is spanning if it contains all the vertices of $G$. A graph is hamiltonian if it has a circuit containing all its vertices.

I have two questions:

> **Question 1** Is it possible to provide an example of a non-hamiltonian, connected, class 1, 4-regular graph?

And

> **Question 2** If a class 1, connected, 4-regular graph $G$ has a class 1, 3-regular connected spanning subgraph $S$, is $G$ Hamiltonian?  If so, is there a Hamilton circuit containing all the edges not in $S$?

Comment: Certainly a disconnected graph. lol, I'll think about it and get back

Comment: @oshill Thank you, I edited the question ... need to think more carefully about the edits, but now is kind of late for me ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph from [here](https://independencenumber.wordpress.com/2014/09/13/round-12-hamiltonicity-sufficient-conditions/), found via a [House of Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/26957) search and also pictured below, is $4$-regular, connected, and class $1$ (as the edge coloring shows), but not Hamiltonian:

[image]

Also, $3$-regular graph formed by the orange, black, and purple edges in the coloring above is connected, so this means that the answer is "no" to both of your questions.

Comment: Thank you! This is quite amazing!